# pandas.series.rolling.apply method seems to implicitly convert Series into numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, type-conversion, numpy-ndarray

I want to compute the rolling volatility of a net value curve.

```
# demo
import pandas as pd

def get_rolling_vol(s: pd.Series) -> float:
    return s.pct_change().iloc[1:].std()

s = pd.Series([1, 1.2, 1.15, 1.19, 1.23, 1.3])
rolling = s.rolling(window=2)
stds = rolling.apply(lambda s: get_rolling_vol(s))
```

Throws error:

```
FutureWarning: Currently, 'apply' passes the values as ndarrays to the applied function. In the future, this will change to passing it as Series objects. You need to specify 'raw=True' to keep the current behaviour, and you can pass 'raw=False' to silence this warning
  stds = rolling.apply(lambda s: get_rolling_vol(s))
... (omits intermediate tracebacks)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'pct_change'
```

Is there any way to make the argument pass as `Series` instead of `ndarrays` in `apply`? The `FutureWarning` says it's gonna be the case in the future, what if I want it now? (Don't want to modify the `get_rolling_vol` function since there are many other functions that also assume the argument is `Series` and modifying all of them will be tedious.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible as stated in the warning message: Use `raw=False` as argument in `rolling.apply`

This works at least in pandas 0.24.1

Comment: No this doesn't work on my machine. Setting raw=True only silences the Warning, but in fact the argument still passes as ndarray.

Comment: Use `raw=False` to get it as a Series and silence the warning.

Comment: As the other comment suggests, it should be `raw=False` instead.